# Polymorphism and Class Structure for Reporting Solution

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm coding a report builder in PHP. These reports will either be shown on a web page, emailed or sent through some other communication line. I'd like to support different types of report data (currently text and tabular).

I've built this and it works, the main classes are:

- ReportBuilder
- ReportMailer
- ITextReport (an interface)
- ITabularReport (an interface)

My concern is that my solution is not extensible, due to my implementation of ReportBuilder:

```
public function addTextReport(ITextReport $report)
{
    $this->textReports[] = $report;

    return $this;
}

public function addTabularReport(ITabularReport $report)
{
    $this->tabularReports[] = $report;

    return $this;
}

public function getData()
{
    $data = ['tabularReports' => [], 'textReports' => []];

    foreach($this->tabularReports as $report)
    {
        $data['tabularReports'][] = [
            'title' => $report->getTitle(),
            'keys'  => $report->getDataTitles(),
            'data'  => $report->getData(),
        ];
    }

    foreach($this->textReports as $report)
    {
        $data['textReports'][] = [
            'title' => $report->getTitle(),
            'content'   => $report->getContent(),
        ];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

My problem:

If I want to add a new report type (say `IGraphReport`), I need to modify `ReportBuilder` to accept this new report type, and then parse it in the `ReportBuilder::getData` method. This violates the Open and Closed principle, and just seems wrong.

Some solutions I considered:

1. Creating a more generic interface `IReport`, with a `render` method on it, and replacing the `addTextReport` and `addTabularReport` in  `ReportBuilder` to a more generic `addReport`. However, the different communication channels require different methods of rendering the data so the `render` method somehow accepts instruction on how to format the data. I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution.

   2. Letting the communication channel decide on how to render reports, but then I envision a number of `if` statements checking the type of the report: `if($report instanceof ITabularReport) { // handle }`, which would then lead me to "replace conditionals with polymorphism" and take me back to point 1.

I'm not sure how to refactor. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a thought, why dont you apply a factory pattern and decorate it with the Report type ? I think the Factory pattern will suffice

Comment: Is there anyway you can expand on that? I'm not connecting the dots as to how that would solve my problem!

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I think I understand now what you meant - use a factory to render the report data. I will try that - thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

Having an `addTextReport` and `addTabularReport` method seems like you're tying yourself to the implementation logic. Why not just have an `addReport` method?

Have each type of `Report` adhere to a contract (interface) which implements the `getData` method. I.e. delegate the responsibility of how the data is returned, to the class.

### ReportBuilder

```
private $reports;

public function addReport(ReportContract $report)
{
    $this->reports[] = $report;
    return $this;
}


public function getData()
{
    $data = [];

    foreach($this->reports as $report) {
        $data[] = $report->getData();
    }

    return $data;
}
```

### ReportContract

```
interface ReportContract
{
    public function getData();
}
```

### ITextReport

```
class ITextReport implements ReportContract
{
    public function getData()
    {
        // return some data
    }
}
```

Now, each new type of report (Graph for example) simply has to implement a `getData` method and your base ReportBuilder class requires no changes or refactoring to support it.

Comment: Thanks for answering Amo! I *do* feel that my implementation isn't very future proof.

I considered your solution - my problem is that the `getData` method returns different data types. For a "text report" this would be a string of text, for a "tabular report" this would be an array, etc. This then leaves me with the problem of how to _render_ the data!

Unless the solution to that is to then create some sort of Factory that returns an appropriate Render object (`HtmlRender`, `AsciiRender`, ...).

Comment: I *could* return a `ReportData` object from the `getData` method... But I'm wondering now if I'm over-complicating things.

Comment: In that case, you may benefit from a ```render``` method on the ```ReportContract```. That way, you can maintain all of the logic for transforming and outputting implementation specific reports in their own class.

Comment: I considered that too - the issue there is that I might need to render a report in HTML for an email, and as plain text to Slack (as an example). Maybe in the future I'd need it rendered as markdown. I think your initial answer has put me in the right direction though - thanks for sharing your insight.